# Redirecting Nginx Parameters

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I inherited a legacy site and for SEO reasons wish to redirect old parameter links to the new api. Like so:

`www.example.com/section/?page=3 => www.example.com/page/3`

Here is my attempt at a regex redirect:

```
location ~ ^/section\/\?page=(.*)/$ {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/page/$1;
}
```

I've used this pattern countless times without issue but after hours of poking I still can't get the redirect working. Clearly Nginx treats parameters differently.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex here, it would add unnecessary processing overhead anyway.

Nginx captures url parameters already. you can use the `$args` variable for all the parameters, or individual ones are prefixed `$arg_`, so assuming all your urls match this format you can just use a location block like this:

```
location  /section/ {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/page/$arg_page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing slash in your regex, so it would only match `www.example.com/section/?page=3/`.

Try `^/section\/\?page=(.*)$`

Comment: Interestingly enough, entering the trailing slash doesn't redirect either. Tried without and still no dice. Sidenote: wouldn't I have to escape the slash in order for it to be captured? I always thought you had to end expression in a closing slash, but then again I'm no expert. Regex has always baffled me somewhat.